# Assigning multiple variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell, iterable-unpacking

Just getting started in Haskell, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to assign multiple variables based on a single condition. So far I've just been packing and unpacking Tuples. Is there a better/more idiomatic way?

```
(var1, var2, var3) = 
    if foo > 0
        then ("Foo", "Bar", 3)
        else ("Bar", "Baz", 1)
```

Also curious about the cost of packing and unpacking the Tuples. If I'm reading [this](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types) correctly, it seems like this gets optimized away in functions, but not sure if that's the case with an assignment.

Comment: You could use lists as well, just so you know. You could even pattern match it in greater chunks using `(a:b:c:rest) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` where `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`, and `rest = [4,5,6]`. Furthermore, this is only necessary in `let` and `where` statements, not in base expression level.

Comment: Since we do not have _mutable_ variables in Haskell, we call these "bindings" or "definitions" rather than "assignments". Your code looks fine, and I wouldn't worry about the cost unless profiling points at it. Also, if you worry about this tuple, you don't want to know how `"Bar"` is actually represented at runtime... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. If you compile with optimizations enabled, the tuples will indeed by "unboxed", so they incur no extra cost. The code will be transformed to something vaguely like this:

```
(# var1, var2, var3 #) = 
    case foo > 0 of
        False -> (# "Bar", "Baz", 1 #)
        True -> (# "Foo", "Bar", 3 #)
```

An unboxed 3-tuple is actually just three values—it doesn't have any sort of extra structure. As a result, it can't be stored in a data structure, but that's okay. Of course, if `foo` is known at compile time, the `case` will be optimized away too, and you'll just get three definitions.